# Parsing human readable calendar in Python

Tags: python, date, parsing

Each train of a railway company travels between a given range of stations only on some dates and only on some days of the week.

The railway company has published a calendar which, for each train, shows when it travels. Texts on this calendar are clearly computer-generated by some script which looks dates up in a database. Sentences generated this way are really hard to understand at first, but they follow some rigid syntactic rules, so parsing them shouldn't be difficult with regular expressions and some string manipulation. Things become complex when dates overlap or are specified in a counter-intuitive way.

I need to write a script which parses this calendar and returns, for each train, the dates and the days of the week on which it travels. Let's assume this calendar is valid for the current year (2018). Here are some example texts and how they should be parsed.

### Example #1

**Original text:**

> From [origin] to [destination] this train does not travel between 2018-01-01 to 2018-06-30 on non-working days.

**Meaning (explained):**

This trains always travels in 2018, but before 07/01 it only travels on working days.

**Example parsed data:**

```
[{"from": "2018-01-01",
   "to": "2018-06-30",
   "days": (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)},  # (mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun)
  {"from": "2018-07-01",
   "to": "2018-12-31",
   "days": (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)}]
```

### Example #2

**Original text:**

> From [origin] to [X] this train travels between 2018-01-01 and 2018-12-31 every day. From [X] to [destination] this trains travels between 2018-01-01 and 2018-08-04 every day, between 2018-08-26 and 2018-12-31 every day. It does not travel between 2018-01-01 and 2018-08-04 on Saturday, on 2018-12-31, between 2018-08-26 and 2018-12-30 on Saturday, on Sunday.

**Meaning (explained):**

From [origin] to [X] the train always travels in 2018. From [X] to [destination] the train travels like so:

- from 01/01 to 08/04 every day but Saturday
- from 08/05 to 08/25 never
- from 08/26 to 12/30 every day but Saturday and Sunday.
- on 12/31 never.

As you can see this one was quite badly phrased and partly contradictory.

**Example parsed data:**

```
# From [origin] to [X]

[{"from": "2018-01-01",
   "to": "2018-12-31",
   "days": (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)}]


# For all the stations after [X]

[{"from": "2018-01-01",
   "to": "2018-08-04",
   "days": (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)},
  {"from": "2018-08-26",
   "to": "2018-12-30",
   "days": (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)}]
```

### Example #3

**Original text:**

> From [origin] to [destination] this train travels between 2018-01-01 and 2018-11-30 on Monday, on Saturday, on 2018-12-25, between 2018-12-30 and 2018-12-31 every day. It does not travel between 2018-12-30 and 2018-12-31 on non-working days, on 2018-11-01.

**Meaning (explained):**

This train in 2018 travels like so:

- from 01/01 to 10/31 on Monday and Saturday
- on 11/01 never
- from 11/02 to 11/30 on Monday and Saturday
- from 12/01 to 12/24 never
- on 12/25 every day
- from 12/26 to 12/29 never
- from 12/30 to 12/31 every day but Sunday

**Example parsed data:**

```
[{"from": "2018-01-01",
  "to": "2018-10-31",
  "days": (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)},
 {"from": "2018-11-02",
  "to": "2018-11-30",
  "days": (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)},
 {"from": "2018-12-25",
  "to": "2018-12-25",
  "days": (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)},
 {"from": "2018-12-30",
  "to": "2018-12-31",
  "days": (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)}]
```

### What I did so far

I split the problem in multiple parts:

1. Extracting data from the text. I split the text into phrases (separated by a period). Then I used regular expressions and string manipulation to determine if it is positive ("travels") or negative ("does not travel"), get the date intervals and the days of the week, the single dates, the single days of the week. If the sentence is negative, I reversed the dates.
2. I converted days of the week (and things like "every day", "working days") into a tuple containing days of the week, as I wrote in the examples. Each tuple is associated with a date interval.
3. The next problem is to merge all the date intervals with the correct data for each day of the week. There may be a Python module to easily do this, but I don't know where to begin (based on how this step is done, the previous ones may need to be completely changed).
4. Another problem is that each station of each train should have its own dates. When the calendar says *from [origin] to [X]* and *from [X] to [destination]*, [X] should be treated in a particular way, as its dates are the union of the dates of the first + second interval.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
It appears that you've simply posted your homework (not properly specified, as you noted), with no effort on your part.  Since the Internet has plenty of tutorial help on program design, language basics, and parsing packages, we're not sure what you expect within the Stack Overflow charter.

Comment: @Prune I'm sorry if I gave this idea. This is not my homework, everything I posted here comes from my own research. I hope it will be ok if I update the question with all the steps I've taken so far to do what I need.

Comment: Yes, please update the question; that would be great.

Comment: @Prune I updated the question with some additional info.

Comment: What you've posted is still a very broad question.  The typical SO question contains a self-sufficient code snippet, with current and desired output.  ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: While the examples are great, it's not entirely clear what your actual problem is. Be specific; show what code you've tried, describe what it did, and what you expected it to do. Remove anything that's working and isn't necessary to duplicating your problem.